# Is there a way to find name of corresponding router-outlet in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a page with severeal named outlets.

Lets say, I have the following outlets, named as w0, w1 and w2, so my url is this:

```
/(w0:something0//w1:something1//w2:something0)
```

As you see, something0 will reside in w0 and in w2.

I need to know in the components code as early as possible (constructor?) the name of the corresponding outlet, where it is placed into. How can I do this?